# operation overloading * (both left side and right side) with template

Tags: c++, class, templates, operator-overloading

I have a class Mat

```
template <class A_Type,int sizeA,int sizeB>
class Matrix {

 ..
..
..
   Matrix operator*(int elem){
        Matrix res = *this;
        res.multiWith(elem);
        return res;
   }
};
```

Now i need it to work with both Mat*2 and 2*Mat

And i have syntax err...

Cant find no example online... any idea how to write it?

Comment: How does `Mat` relate to `Matrix<A_Type,sizeA,sizeB>` actually?

Comment: _"And i have syntax err..."_ Please always provide compiler errors verbatim in your question. Also you should always provide a [MCVE] of your code, that reproduces the problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Now i need it to work with both Mat*2 and 2*Mat

You write a global operator overload:

```
 template<class A_Type,int sizeA,int sizeB>
 Matrix<A_Type,sizeA,sizeB> operator*(int,const Matrix<A_Type,sizeA,sizeB>&);

 template<class A_Type,int sizeA,int sizeB>
 Matrix<A_Type,sizeA,sizeB> operator*(const Matrix<A_Type,sizeA,sizeB>&,int);
```

---

Something like:

```
template <class A_Type,int sizeA,int sizeB>
class Matrix {

     template<class U_Type,int sizeX,int sizeX>
     friend Matrix<U_Type,sizeX,sizeY> operator*(int elem,const Matrix<U_Type,sizeX,sizeY>& m) {
        Matrix<U_Type,sizeX,sizeY> res = m;
        res.multiWith(elem);
        return res;     
     }

     template<class U_Type,int sizeX,int sizeX>
     friend Matrix<U_Type,sizeX,sizeY> operator*(const Matrix<U_Type,sizeX,sizeY>& m, int elem) {
         return operator*(elem,m);     
     }
};
```

Comment: @JohnnyF Of course I'm sure. You probably implemented this wrong. Want a full sample?

Comment: global operstor overloads often behave poorly with templates: maybe use koenig adl based friends instead?

Comment: @Yakk _"maybe use koenig adl based friends instead?"_ I don't know that pattern, you want to write an answer (or edit mine)?

Comment: Bah nm you already did it.  Serves me right for just reading the first few lines.

Comment: just to understand, can i jsut do the global overload, or inside the class  I must add a friend blabla?

Comment: @JohnnyF It's a global overload of that operator declared and defined as `friend` inside to class declaration. IMHO the easiest syntactically.